# Can I replace a layer with another in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, effects, animation-rendering

I made a logo in Photoshop. I imported it in After Effects where I animated it, I added effects, I duplicated it etc.

Unfortunately I realized that the logo wasn't ready, I needed to add something else, a final touch, which had to be done in the source ie. in Photoshop. So I did change it in Photoshop, I imported the new one in the After Effects project.

Now I spent about a good day's time doing all the effects etc on the previous logo. Is it possible that I can replace the old logo (the old layer) with the new layer such that I won't have to redo all the effects and animations etc. to the new layer all over again?

gee if this isn't possible I will break down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Simply right-click your logo in the Project-Panel and select "replace file", then select your new logo.

Comment: Also if you were modifying the original file and didn't add any layers, when you save a .PSD file in photoshop, the file in After Effects should update a few seconds afterwards.

Comment: @tomh is absolutely right. If the PSD doesn't update in AE after saving in photoshop, you might need to right-click the source and press "reload footage". I've had some issues with it not updating sometimes, but 90% of the time that method works just fine.